# Take iframe from div A and display it in div B?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to take iframe from one div and display it in another div, but smoothly as page loads, not to look like it first shows in originaly div and than jumps out to new one.

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="iframer"></div>
    <div class="iframer-2">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/00000" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0"></iframe>
    </div>
</article>
```

The final result should place iframe from "iframer-2" into "iframer", and it would look like this...

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="iframer">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/00000" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="iframer-2"></div>
</article>
```

I found code somewhere here long ago, but I can not now, I forgot what title was this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what the goal is in a general context but I believe you are looking for something like this: use detach and appendTo to move the iframe and SlideUp and SlideDown to to soften the effect

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elm =  $(".iframer-2").children('iframe');
  elm.slideUp('normal', function() { 
     elm.detach().appendTo(".iframer");
     elm.slideDown('normal');
  });   
});
```

If you don't want i frame to appear in the original div just start with display: none

```
.iframer-2{
   display:none;
}
```